# How can I use multiple delimiters in d3.dsv?

Tags: regex, csv, d3.js

I have data in the following format:

```
# first_col    second_col   third_col
 filename1           2.3        -4.5
   filename2       -3           1
 filename3          -4        1.5000000
```

where basically columns are separated by a variable amount of spaces and tabs.

It is the default way `gnuplot` reads data files.

How can I use the `d3.dsv()` methtod of `d3.js` to read it? in the [API example](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#dsv) I see something like

```
var dsv = d3.dsv("|", "text/plain");
```

where `|` is the delimiter, but there is a way to tell him that I want one or multiple instances of characters, for example with a regular expression?

[This other example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/m-G-5DCk8WI) involves jquery but I'd prefere a pure d3 solution.

Comment: You can't do this with the current implementation of `d3.dsv`; the separator has to be a single character.

Comment: There is a `d3` method to use as workaround, for example to substitute these multiple characters with a comma and then use `d3.csv`?

Comment: You can use the same approach as in the example you've linked to with [`d3.xhr`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_xhr).

Comment: Do you mean `d3.xhr` instead of jQuery `$.get()`? Ok, I'll try